# How to specify the number of citation

Tags: bibtex, bibliographystyle

I was working in rapport using latex, and lately start using beamer in my presentation and I add some references of latex and I want them to be the same number.

```
[56] www.sqlservertutorial.net. What is sql server. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/
getting-started/what-is-sql-server, 03/10/2022. Last accessed 10 Mars 2022.
```

like this reference it's automatically use the number [56], i want it to be [20]

and you should know that i'm using natbib package using \bibliographystyle{plain} and \bibliography{Bibliography}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: don't use bibtex on the new document: simply `\input` the bbl file of the first, then the references will have the same numbers.

Comment: can you provide some piece of code as answer if you can please!

Comment: We need to know more about your setup if you want more concrete help. You've tagged your question with both `biblatex` and BibTeX/`\bibliographystyle`, but the BibTeX/`\bibliographystyle` approach is fundamentally different from the `biblatex` approach. We can't say anything useful until we know which approach you use.

Comment: i'm using natbib using \bibliographystyle{plain} and \bibliography{Bibliography}

Comment: Please edit your question to specify this. Then David's approach would work, but it would force all entries of the report to appear also in the presentation, which might not be desired.